# Prove that if $n \geq 2$, then $n! < \{{2n \atop n}\} < (2n)!$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that if $n \ge 2$, then $$n! < \left\{{2n \atop n}\right\} < (2n)!.$$

Here, $\{{2n \atop n}\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

I have absolutely no idea how to start this question - could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: In the title you give the Stirling numbers of the first kind, in the main text you give the second kind. Which one are you considering?

Comment: What is $s(2n,n)$?

Comment: My bad, it's a typo - I was referring to the second kind and I have edited the question to make that more clear :)

Comment: @user890948 I think it is more clear if there is a definition or a link to a definition. I've edited it in for you, and of course you already got an answer, but in the future, I think including such a link would be more effective. And I also recommend typing equations out instead of using images, but I appreciate the difficulty of typesetting $\{{2n \atop n}\}$ if you've never done it before.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, $S(2n, n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 2n \\ n \end{array} \right\}$ counts the number of ways to partition a $2n$-element set into $n$ non-empty sets. So let's try to compare this number with permutations.

So first, let's look at a permutation of $n$ elements. For instance the permutation

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

and oh hey we can get a set partition out of that:

$$\{1,8\}, \{2, 10\}, \{3, 6\}, \{4,9\}, \{5,7\}.$$

So evidently $n! \le S(2n, n)$ and except when $n = 1$ this inequality should be strict.

Next, let's take a set partition and attempt to get a unique permutation of $2n$ elements out of it. Let's say

$$\{1,2,3\}, \{4,9\}, \{5\}, \{6,8,10\}, \{7\}.$$

Do we get a unique permutation out of it? I only see one reasonable thing to do so let's try it:

$$\{\{1,2,3\}, \{4,9\}, \{5\}, \{6,8,10\}, \{7\}\} \mapsto (1,2,3)(4,9)(5)(6,8,10)(7)$$

Is this well-defined/injective? Well it looks like we need to fix an ordering on the $2n$ elements ahead of time so that $\{1,2,3\} \mapsto (1,2,3)$ is well-defined. But after that, yeah, that looks like it should work.

You should write these maps in a general form (rather than $n = 5$) and check the details (well-defined/injective). Also check if/when you get strict inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still unsure of a combinatorial/algebraic proof to this.

Comment: @user890948 Well, my answer is an outline of a combinatorial proof, and Claude's answer is an outline of the algebraic approach (but only asymptotically).